# When should I use sublist syntax in function definition

Tags: python, python-2.7

The formal syntax for function definitions, presented in [*7.6. Function Definitions of Python Language Reference*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions), is as follows:

```
decorated      ::=  decorators (classdef | funcdef)
decorators     ::=  decorator+
decorator      ::=  "@" dotted_name ["(" [argument_list [","]] ")"] NEWLINE
funcdef        ::=  "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")" ":" suite
dotted_name    ::=  identifier ("." identifier)*
parameter_list ::=  (defparameter ",")*
                    (  "*" identifier ["," "**" identifier]
                    | "**" identifier
                    | defparameter [","] )
defparameter   ::=  parameter ["=" expression]
sublist        ::=  parameter ("," parameter)* [","]
parameter      ::=  identifier | "(" sublist ")"
funcname       ::=  identifier
```

Notice the `sublist` syntax of `parameter`, which makes possible for example the following function definition:

```
def f((a,b,c), d):
    return a,b,c,d
```

However, I've never seen any Python code ever used this `sublist` syntax (just for my very limited experience with Python). Here are my questions:

- In what situations would the `sublist` syntax be a better idea compared to other possibilities provided by the formal function definition syntax (kwargs, `*iterable` and `**mapping`, to name a few)?
- Are there any real-world (i.e. practical) usage examples to make it actually useful?

Comment: Note that this syntax was removed in python 3.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Oh, thanks for that, to you and to python community.

Comment: the reasoning for removing the syntax can be viewed here: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason would be if the data itself is best represented as a list or a tuple but you are referring to its individual elements more that the list itself. Take for example this function which calculates the distance between 2 points:

```
def distance_between_points((x1, y1), (x2, y2)):
    return math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
```

This looks much better than doing:

```
def distance_between_points(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p2[0]-p1[0])**2 + (p2[1]-p0[1])**2)
```